# Is it possible to use Google-friendly URLs in WSS 3.0 site?

Tags: sharepoint, seo, url-rewriting, wss-3.0

I have website designed in WSS 3.0 (Windows SharePoint Services 3.0). Can i re-write URLs to Google / SEO friendly URLs? If yes then please do let me know how to do it?

---

Thanks,
Rau.

Answer (score 2):

The best/easiest way would be to do it the way we've always done it - with an HTTP module intercepting the requests.  Install it to the GAC via WSP, and make the web.config changes through a feature receiver - make sure the feature is defined with a web application scope.

Note that for publishing pages, the "/pages" part of the url is required to be supported by Microsoft.  So, in your solution, be sure to serve up pages to both their modified & original URLs, so you can browse to "/pages/whatever.aspx" whenever you need to make changes to your content.

Answer (score 1):

It was done before, as Greg said -- usign url-rewrite modules and theres also well documented ways to [fix the 302 Temporarily Moved](http://www.helloitsliam.com/archive/2009/05/15/moss2007-%E2%80%93-302-to-301-%E2%80%9Cpages%E2%80%9D-redirect.aspx). You can also make use of this [IIS Rewrite](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/friendly-urls-sharepoint-site-4-steps-iis7-url-rewrite-module/) option for friendly urls, and a few [configuration tweaks](http://blogs.sharepointlabs.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=9312760c-c235-4cc0-a25f-481a34785c3d&ID=21), all this applied to the WSS limitations, of course.